# Runtime errors trying to run a macOS AudioKit app

Tags: xcode, audiokit

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a macOS audiokit project to run properly.

I've cloned the repo and opened one of the example projects - `examples/macOS/HelloWorld`. It builds fine, with no errors, but then when I try to run it I get this error:

`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AudioKitUI.framework/Versions/A/AudioKitUI`

which is reasonable since the readme says that the UI Framework has to listed in the embedded binaries list. So I update my project to include AudioKitUI.framework in the embedded binaries list, rebuild and run, then I get a bunch of errors like this:

`Class <AudiokitUI classes> is implemented in both <.../Build/Products/Debug/HelloWorld.app/Contents/Frameworks/AudioKitUI.framework/Versions/A/AudioKitUI> and <.../Build/Products/Debug/HelloWorld.app/Contents/MacOS/HelloWorld>`

I'm using:

- xcode 10.0
- macOS v10.13.6

I've just installed xcode for this project, and I haven't changed any of the defaults.

Comment: is this `HelloWorld` project public on GitHub?  It might be old/outdated or in need of an update.

Comment: The messages are warnings, not strictly errors, for me anyway. What is causing the error?

Comment: Oof, I can confirm that macOS AudioKit is messed up in Xcode10.  We're working on it.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - for clarity, this is the HelloWorld that comes along as part of the AudioKit repo, and I cloned it yesterday, so I'd assume it's up to date.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka - I'm glad that it wasn't something crazy on my end, but I'm sorry to hear it seems so unexpectedly broken with the new xcode release. For what it's worth I got a similar failure when I tried to build an iOS example. I'm new to mac/iOS development, but I've been in software for many years - let me know if there's anything I can do to help you sort this out.

Comment: The culprit is definitely AudioKitUI.  If you don't absolutely need it in your project, just remove it until we have this worked out.

Comment: This is basically fixed on the develop branch and will be in AK 4.4.1, just doing a bunch more testing before releasing it (we broke a lot!).